# searching code for particular text then deleting it and replacing it with another word

Tags: excel, vba

I have code to delete a certain word in vba project code and replace it with another. I can't seem to get it to work. Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Dim myBook As Object
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim strToReplaceWith As String, strToReplace As String, Replacing As String, Replaced As               
String

n = Range("L10").Value
Replacing = "Data_Acq_1Gal"
Replaced = "Data_Acq_1Gal " & "(" & n & ")"
Set myBook = ActiveWorkbook.VBProject
For Each myBook In Application.Workbooks
For i = 1 To myBook.VBProject.VBComponents.Count
For j = 1 To 34
If InStr(1, myBook.VBProject.VBComponents(i).CodeModule.Lines(j, 1), Replacing, vbTextCompare) Then       
myBook.VBProject.VBComponents(i).CodeModule.DeleteLines j
strToReplace = myBook.CodePanes.Item(i).CodeModule.Lines(j, 1)
strToReplaceWith = Replace(strToReplace, Replacing, Replaced, 1, 1, vbTextCompare)
myBook.VBProject.VBComponents(i).CodeModule.InsertLines j, strToReplaceWith
End If
Next j
Next i
Next myBook

End Sub
```

Comment: `For j = 1 To 34` Why 34?

Comment: I was only wanting to search a piece of the code for what i wanted to replace, because i knew that the items didn't exist below line 34.

Answer (score 0):

One major flaw in your code is that if it runs successfully then it will overwrite the search string in your module as well. To ensure that it doesn't do that we will pad our search string with a predefine string. I am using `#$%@` for the padding.

Is this what you are trying?

```
'~~> We need so that the code doesn't replace the search string in itself
Const sPad As String = "#$%@"

Sub Sample()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject
    Dim VBComp As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim CodeMod As VBIDE.CodeModule
    Dim WordToReplace As String, NewWord As String
    Dim ActualSearchWord As String, NewString As String
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    n = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("L10").Value

    '~~> Padding our search string
    WordToReplace = sPad & "Data_Acq_1Gal ()" & sPad
    ActualSearchWord = Replace(WordToReplace, sPad, "")
    NewWord = "Data_Acq_1Gal " & "(" & n & ")"

    For Each wb In Workbooks
        '~~> Remove the below IF/ENDIF if you want the code to replace 
        '~~> in other modules of this workbook
        If wb.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then 
            Set VBProj = wb.VBProject

            For Each VBComp In VBProj.VBComponents
                Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule
                With CodeMod
                    j = .CountOfLines

                    For i = 1 To j
                        If InStr(1, .Lines(i, 1), ActualSearchWord, vbTextCompare) > 0 And _
                        InStr(1, .Lines(i, 1), WordToReplace, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                            NewString = Replace( _
                                                 .Lines(i, 1), _
                                                 ActualSearchWord, _
                                                 NewWord, 1, , vbTextCompare)
                            .ReplaceLine i, NewString
                        End If
                    Next i
                End With
            Next VBComp
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have issue on the top part at Dim VBProj As VBIDE.VBProject. It comes up with error User Defined Type not Defined. Any ideas of what i am not including?

Comment: Ok I figured out the user defined type. I had to add the extensibility reference. One problem i am having is this code is set to go through each sheets project and change. I just want it to go through the active sheet project. So if the sheet the user is on is sheet 21 then that is the sheet it should search the macro for the offending text. Where would i change this at? I appreciate your help so far. It works very smoothly!

Comment: Posting from phone so please ignore any typos...  For this to work you have to set a reference to `Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3` (version may vary), by clicking the Tools > References menu in VBA Editor.

Comment: Sorry there is a delay in posting from phone. Glad your problem regarding reference is sorted. Now you want it to work for only activesheet?

Comment: yes because i am using your code on a button so it will only change for that particular sheet when they click the button.

Comment: OK I am out at the moment and will return little late in the night. Let me write and test it before posting :)

Comment: Ok Thank you! Your knowledge is greatly appreciated.